# Ant JUnit failure with french thousands separator

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

Using Netbeans 6.9.1 my unit tests pass without issue.  Using junit (4.8.2, which seems to be the same version that Netbeans uses) the tests fail on the command line.

The failure has to do with this line:

```
assertEquals("x doit être >= 10 et < 100, était la suivante: 1 000", messages_fr.between("x", 10, 100, 1000));
```

On the command line the message displays as:

> x doit ├¬tre >= 10 et < 100, ├⌐tait la
>   suivante: 1á000

I am at a loss for what is going on.  I know that the thousands separator is not a space but 0XA0, no issue with that, but the fact that Netbeans and the command line are in disagreement about it is a real issue.

I am using ant 1.8.1 which is also the same version as Netbeans.   It happens on OS X (10.6.5) and Windows 7.  I still need to check Ubuntu 10.10.

Any ideas why it works in Netbeans but not on the command line in ant?

Comment: Would be worth checking whether the locale and encoding settings used by Ant are in agreement with those used by Netbeans.  What does your 'between' method do though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the inconsistency in the output: `ê` and `é` look like UTF-8 displayed as CP437, whereas no-break space looks like Windows-1252 displayed as CP437.

Let's put aside the fact that the console encoding (CP437) doesn't match the system encoding (Windows-1252). Then I assume that no-break space is represented properly, since it comes from the runtime library. This means that UTF-8 in representation of the message is an error. Perhaps template of your message is stored in UTF-8, but loaded as Windows-1252. If this template is stored in the code, you need to set compiler encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: turns out I had not set junit or javac to encode as utf-8.  Took me a while to track down the issue (I changed javac for the source but not the unit tests).  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction... I never would have though I had to pass the encoding to javac.

Answer (score 1):

I think you problem is the encoding. You can try to change the encoding of your Java class (from ISO to UTF or viceversa).

If this doesn't work, you can try to configure Ant to use the same encoding Netbeans does.

If this doesn't work too, you can try to write a method that convert your message in another message without special characters.

In Spain we have the same problems, and many times we write every string with no special character (not the best solution, but it works).